# Is castling legal regarding rooks passing over attacked squares?

Tags: rules, castling

I was playing a game of chess and I was playing black. I had a rook on b2. I had control of the b1 square. My opponent white did not have any pawns in the second  rank. My opponent; white castled queenside. Is it illegal for his rook to pass the b1 square considering his rook passed the b1 square I had control of. Wouldn't it make this castle move illegal on white's part?

Answer (score 8):

It is still possible to castle if the **rook** passes through squares that are attacked(under control by opponent's rook e.g. as you say), it's only in the case of the **king** that such scenario prohibits you from castling.

Have a look at the post Cleveland has suggested in the comments.

Here's an example anyway:

```
[Title "O-O-O"]
[StartFlipped "0"]
[fen "2bk2nr/p1p2ppp/2p5/2p5/2P1P3/2N5/Pr3PPP/R3KB1R w KQkq - 0 1"]

1.O-O-O+
```